# implementing delegate in interface

Tags: c#, events, interface, callback, delegates

I can't find a way to implement delegate in interface

I want to get this:

```
public class SomeClass : ISomeInterface
{
    public delegate void SomeCallback();
    public SomeCallback callback;

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
         callback.invoke();
    }
}

public class MainClass
{
    void Callback() { Console.WriteLine("Callback"); }

    public void Start()
    {
         SomeClass s = new SomeClass();
         s.callback = Callback;
         s.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

but in case when I create instance of the class "SomeClass" using interface:

```
public class MainClass
{

    void Callback() { Console.WriteLine("Callback"); }

    public void Start()
    {
         ISomeInterface s = new SomeClass();   // <<<----
         s.callback = Callback;                // here will be an error :(
         s.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

Please, help me with it :)

Comment: Well, of course. If you are treating `s` as an `ISomeInterface`, it has no idea about anything to do with `SomeClass`. When you implement or extend `ISomeInterface`, your additions don't magically make it back upstream to the interface.  If you want to use members you declared in `SomeClass`, you'll have to treat it as a `SomeClass`.

Comment: maybe there is some trick for that? i just want to get callbacks from objects created this way (using interfaces)

Comment: it would be great if i could assign delegates using some method declared in interface

Comment: You *can* use the `is` or `as` operators to check and see if your `ISomeInterface` variable is *actually* a `SomeClass`. However, I would ask why are you even treating your objects as an interface at that point, if you really need details of a concrete implementation? If you're simply wanting the callback to be part of the interface, then change its declaration to a property: `SomeCallback callback {get; set;}`

Comment: Could you tag this question to include the language.  It may help you get more views...

Comment: Sure :)
"s" in this example can be any of several different classes that do same stuff in a different way. for example, it can be AndroidConnectionService or IOSConnectionService and both implement IConnectionService interface. i need to get callbacks from these objects without "asking" them about their classes

Comment: ((SomeClass)s).callback = Callback;

Comment: it is a good idea, but i have more than one callback and this code will grow :(

Comment: If you want the callback to a property of the interface, then it needs to be declared in the interface. That's really the only way you can do what you're asking for.

Comment: can you please edit my code this way?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/3cdbe1d3280e6f6f80ecd4f18df439d3
i cant implement this interface member correctly - it gives error all the time :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moving the callback to the interface is required if you want to use the callback without casing to a concrete type. Note that your current implementation has `callback` as a *field*. To declare it in an interface, you must make it a *property*.

Because *properties* are really methods, you must implement the property in your concrete class. Using an auto-property is fine for the implementation here.

Once you've made those changes, you can then set and call the callback using only the interface.

```
public delegate void SomeCallback();

public interface ISomeInterface {
    SomeCallback callback { get; set; }
    void SomeMethod();
}

public class SomeClass : ISomeInterface
{
    public SomeCallback callback { get; set; }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        callback.Invoke();
    }
}

public class MainClass
{
    void Callback() { Console.WriteLine("Callback"); }

    public void Start()
    {
        ISomeInterface s = new SomeClass();
        s.callback = Callback;
        s.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```